# Max number of items in a list in Recycler View adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Hello,
                                                                                                                                           I was wondering just how many items can mData take before OOM? 
I mean if i do an infinte scroll in published app will it throw OOM?

```
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<String> mData;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private ItemClickListener mClickListener;

// data is passed into the constructor
MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<String> data) {
    this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.mData = data;
}


 ..............

}
```

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski lol, really and what device could crash?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski true, i just checked and had OOM with less then 3 million strings. "to be or not to be" + i

Answer (score -1):

If you question about list of Strings it only depends on how long your strings is. In general 1 char of string = 1 byte(depends on encode). So the answer will be depends on free memory alocated to you application.

Comment: -Im not reffering to the recycler view but the variable that holds the list of the total items. How should i know how many items can i display? e.x i want millions, will the app crash?

Comment: In this case you shouldn't use Adapter for this question. If you question about list of Strings it only depends on how long your strings is.  In general 1 char of string = 1 byte(depends on encode). So the answer will be depends on free memory alocated to you application.

Comment: So lets say that with every scroll on the recycler, a list of names (taken from a database) are added in the list and therefor updates the recycler view. If i keep scrolling the size of the list will keep on rizing. What am i asking is, is there a solution to this or it depends on the device?

Comment: @Nick Depends on the device means that every device have a different amount of memory. I just tested and had crash with less then 3 millions strings.

Comment: Ok so do i put a limit on the size of the array? Is this a good approach? I havent seen it elsewhere

Comment: because nobody needs millions of records on device at once and I bet you do not need it either. It smells like bad design

Comment: Don't limmit you list. For your uncommon case would be better to use onLowMemory() method in activity/fragment then create logic to save position where you list now. Then clear the list and upload new data but also you have to think about logic if user start scrolling back.